# Static function highlighting/locking in C++

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, c++

In C++ mode, I am finding that `static` functions are only highlighted when written in the form `static ReturnType function_name(args)`, and not when written `ReturnType static function_name(args)`.

Image:

[image]

Is there some subtly in the placement of the `static` keyword I'm missing here?
I prefer to place it on the right, to be consistent with the way I do it for variables - which it doesn't have any problem with:

[image]

If the two function declarations are equivalent, I'd appreciate any help getting the first to be highlighted.

**EDIT**:

The problem also exists with variables that aren't declared automatically.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in cc-mode. I suggest that you report it to the Emacs team.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get that sent.